# m.route.param returns "undefined"

Tags: javascript, mithril.js

I have routing defined:

```
m.route(document.getElementById('artists'), "/", {
        "/auth/:token/:refresh": {
          onmatch: (args) => {
                     ...
          }
        }
  });
```

and when I open URL mysite/#!/auth/456456/54645646 and I try to debug my code with

```
console.log( m.route.param('token'), m.route.param('refresh'));
```

I get only undefined. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In principle there's nothing wrong with how you're using the APIs, but a few things could be going awry. Going by the way you've structured your dummy code, it could be you're trying to invoke `m.route.param` from inside `onmatch`. In this case, the problem would be that `m.route.get` & `m.route.param` will query the *currently resolved* route, and until a RouteResolver's  `onmatch` function has finished executing - or in the case where it returns a promise, that that promised has resolved - then the route is not yet considered to be current (the previous route, if any, will be exposed in `m.route.param`). The way to query the route that is being matched is to invoke `onmatch`'s argument.

[This demo queries the different available APIs at different times](https://flems.io/#0=N4Igxg9gdgzhA2BTEAucD4EMAONEBMQAaEAMwEskZUBtUKTAW2TQDoArakyKAF0T6oQjVgCcIAV34AKADpQABAvwQwE5n1YAjCPgCeRBfKUByAPSYpACzMAWAKwA2B47P3bzpx5OHjC4H5KsiAW1mYovBAA1gLhooik8TBWwSj+gUoK0IyYvGBWabm8ojAKALwAfOmKmbU8cEis8BAA5tIm2bn5JgCUGbX9mfUIiE2tcjW1tSbYmKJMCgCOEoiiemk+g7Ui4lKjs-OM7ZExUL2+k1NKO5L8rAdM7fGJiMnnWwo9ANwfH8ONzTaH1MRRKSxWaw2RGBClBMFYJwE0MuVzhYgSSSsyKuSm+gwAvtipoN4lB8Ks0tJgHD8T1ylUAiihtAGqNAU8BOTRL0fkygnyFP82eMYTM5gtlqt1gpNgLrmJbvtxUcTIizj0LjjMjc9vdlRyXm8NR88QK-iyRmMgXKZXDwVKoTC0WqiVq0c9Ma6pqatR94rwJKJFEcdXcADLkKBRQyMrVKKzPDahXg2RzuNO2MwARgATABmHO5vNZ2VawkygAq8wAboh4L0CRl8X5m1BvsQQHgkGBeOQWUIs1mUHm8yB8QBdEjwSNRagoOggBjMISMcgp0SUDuB+BCKy8Xi4FBmMwSKDYKItViQRhmVfrygAARzrAADKxM3eE5RWKuoBwuCAvB6NgLCdmAG7YLwY7jviQA).

If this doesn't solve your issue, please come and discuss it [in the Mithril chatroom](https://gitter.im/mithriljs/mithril.js) where we can discuss the problem in detail!